# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in angular 4

Tags: angular, primeng

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in angular 4**

this is code
    export class UserComponent implements OnInit{

```
  roles:IUserRole[];
  sourseRoles: SelectedItem[];
  selectedRole:any;

BindRoles() {
    this.sourseRoles= [];
    this.sourseRoles.push({ label: "Assign Role", value: null });
    if (this.roles.length > 0) {
      for (let role of this.roles) {
        this.sourseRoles.push({ label: role.Title, value: role.UserRoleId })enter image description here
      }
    }
  }
----------
```

this is code

> this.appServiceManager.libGet("Role")
>                .subscribe((role: any) => {
>                  this.selectedRole= [];
>
> ```
>            this.selectedRole = role;
>            this.sourseRoles.push({ label: this.selectedRole.Title, value: this.selectedRole.UserRoleId })
>          },
>          (error: any) => {
>            this.msgs = [];
>
>            this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error Message', detail: error });
>          });
> ```

```
----------
<label for="password">User Role</label>
 <p-dropdown name="Title" #Title="ngModel" required (click)="BindRoles()" 

 [(ngModel)]="selectedRole" id="dropdown" [options]="sourseRoles"

 [autoWidth]="false"></p-dropdown>

 <div *ngIf="registerForm.submitted && !Title.valid" class="help-block">Role 
 Information is required</div>

----------
```

Comment: initialize the value of roles...

Comment: @Jota.Toledo is correct you should initialize your array of  roles, otherwise you will have that error

Comment: @mahsam sorry i dont write sourseRoles plz again i edit this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    roles: IUserRole[] = [];     <======= Initialize it =========>
    sourseRoles: SelectedItem[]; <======= Declaration was incorrect =========>
    selectedRole: any;

    BindRoles() {
      if (this.roles.length > 0) {
        for (let role of this.roles) {
          this.sourseRoles.push({ label: role.Title, value: role.UserRoleId })
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this in the TS code:

```
sourseRoles
```

I see your roles and selectedRole

Comment: I get roles by webapi serveice